# SQL counting columns with same userID

Tags: sql

I have two tables.   Table 1 contains content_id's that meets a certain criteria.   Table 2 contains the content_id, content, and related user_id.   They share a content_id field.   I would like to produce a list of who has the most entries in Table 1.

Example

Table 1
content_id {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Table 2
content_id|user_id { 1|2 , 2|3 , 3|2 , 4|1 , 5|3, 6|2 }

Desired results
user 2 has 3 entries
user 3 has 2 entries
user 1 has 1 entry

I imagine I need to INNER JOIN the two tables by content_id and then somehow use COUNT or similar?

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to "filter" by the content of t1, one possibility is:

```
create table t1 (content_id int);
insert into t1 values (2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
-- note I ommitted 1 so not all values are present

create table t2 (content_id int, user_id int);
insert into t2 (values (1,2), (2,3) , (3,2) , (4,1) , (5,3), (6,2) );

select user_id, count(*) from t2 where exists (select 1 from t1 where content_id=t2.content_id) group by user_id;

-- output:
 user_id | count 
---------+-------
       3 |     2
       2 |     2
       1 |     1
(3 rows)


-- OR

select user_id, count(*) from  (select * from t2 except select 1 as user_id, content_id from t1) AS filtered group by user_id;

-- output:

 user_id | count 
---------+-------
       3 |     2
       2 |     2
       1 |     1
(3 rows)
```

But other answers are already doing this too.

Comment: petre, that works great thanks.   is it possible to sort by count?   in your outputs they are sorted by count but i think that's a coincidence of the data.   my output from my query isn't sorted by the count.

Comment: yes. just add an `order by 2` or `order by count` or explicitly name the output column :`select user_id, count(*) as number_of_stuff .... order by number_of_stuff`

Comment: nice that works great.   one more complication - user_id - I'd like to extract the user_name from table 3 which contains user_id and user_name, and then my result would be only user_name and count, instead of user_id and count.   can i include that in this query?

Comment: that's a straight forward join on user_id.

Comment: not sure how or where to add it.   working query:  select user_id, count(*) as number_of_stuff from t2 where exists (select 1 from t1 where content_id=t2.content_id) group by user_id order by number_of_stuff   ----    i tried:  select user_id, count(*) as number_of_stuff from t2 where exists (select 1 from t1 where content_id=t2.content_id) inner join t3 on t2.user_id = t3.user_id group by user_id order by number_of_stuff   but it didn't work

Comment: Hi @Lardog. This is beginning to look like a conversation where you are asking more and more questions. Please consider raising a new question, or update your original question. Not sure how this should be approached on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a simple `group by`?

```
select user_id, count(*)
from table2
group by user_id;
```

EDIT:

If you want to restrict the content ids, I recommend `exists`:

```
select t2.user_id, count(*)
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t1.content_id = t2.content_id
             )
group by user_id;
```

Comment: only want results from table2 where content_id also exists in table 1

Comment: @Lardog . . . In your sample data, all the content ids are in table 1 -- as I would expect if the tables are representing a proper relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet that will produce your desired result:

```
Select 
tb2.user_id,count(tb2.content_id) 
From table1 tb1 
Inner join table2 tb2 
on tb1.content_id=tb2.content_id 
group by tb2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

### I hope this what you looking for and help you

```
select user_id, count(`content_id`) from table2 t2 
where exists (select t1.content_id from table1 t1 
where t1.content_id=t2.content_id) 
group by user_id order BY count(`content_id`) DESC;

+---------+---------------------+
| user_id | count(`content_id`) |
+---------+---------------------+
|       2 |                   3 |
|       3 |                   2 |
|       1 |                   1 |
+---------+---------------------+
```